# Query STI And Return List Containing Specific Types

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a typical single table inheritance case, something like:

```
class Instrument < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.search(params)
    query = Instrument
    # build up the query scope
    query
  end
end

class Guitar < Instrument
end

class Trumpet < Instrument
end
```

I need to get a single paginated list of instruments of all kinds.

```
@instruments = Instrument.search(params)
  .page(params[:page])
  .per(params[:size])
```

My problem is that each model in the search results is an Instrument, whereas I need them to be `Guitar`s and `Trumpet`s, etc or else subclass methods like `#blow` and `#strum` are missing.

Because of pagination, I can't really do multiple queries.

Surely this is a common use case that ActiveRecord supports, and I'm just missing something obvious, yes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you have added a type column to the instruments table, migrated the database and restarted the server?

Any Instrument object that is loaded from the database, assuming it has a type set, should automatically be loaded as the subclass.

Are you positive the values in the type column are being stored correctly?
I believe the class name in the type column is case-sensitive.